# Slope from Linear fit in Mathematica

Tags: fitting

I have two lists of data of equal number of points. I want to find slope in *Mathematica*. The *MATLAB* code is as under P = polyfit(log10(dw),gg,1);

Where P(1) is the slope. How to find this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Look up `LinearModelFit` or `FindFit` in the *Mathematica* documentation.

Comment: Thanks to all. Finally I got the answer